# Git workflow for data analysis projects

Tags: git, data-analysis

I am using Git for different software projects for quite a while and I follow in general this [workflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Recently, I started to work with data analysis projects and I wonder what workflow might be best suitable here. Does anybody have experience with Git in this context or suggestions about how to handle these kind of projects in Git? I am not sure if the branches master, develop and feature_branches might be the optimal solution for continuous data analytics.

Answer (score -1):

I found this to be helpful for thinking about data analysis and git, and I think the author based it on the workflow you mention in your question http://christianlemp.com/blog/2014/02/13/How-I-Manage-Data-Projects-with-RStudio-and-Git-Part-2.html